# Prove A Series Of Functions Does Not Converge In Measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $f_n: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f_n (\omega) = \omega(1 + \frac{1}{n})$ and let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure.

I have to show that $f_n$ does not converge in measure $\mu$ to $\omega$.

Here's my attempt:
By definition, $f_n$ converges in measure to $\omega$ if:

$\forall \delta > 0$, $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu (\omega: |f_n (\omega) - \omega| \ge \delta) = 0.$

Rewriting, it becomes that: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mu (\omega: |\omega| \ge n \cdot \delta) = 0.$$

I realized that if $\delta = 1$ for example, then the measure is surely $0$ as $n \to \infty$. I need to come up with a value of $\delta$ such that the measure is non-zero. I thought about letting $\delta = \frac{1}{n},$ but am unsure if it'll become indeterminate once I set $n \to \infty$ (because I basically get $\infty \cdot \frac{1}{\infty}). $

Does this solution of $\delta = \frac{1}{n}$ truly work as a counterexample? If not, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter what $\delta$ is. $\mu (\omega: |\omega| \ge n \cdot \delta) = \infty$ for every $n$ and every $\delta$.

$\{\omega: |\omega| \ge n \cdot \delta\}=[n\delta, \infty)\cup (-\infty, -n\delta]$.

Comment: I don't quite understand - if $n \to \infty$, doesn't the interval just becomes $[\infty, \infty) \implies$ it has measure $0$? How do you find measure of infinite quantities?

Comment: You have to first write down the measure of the set and then take the limit as $n \to \infty$. You are  reversing the order.  @sfs2007